# The metaphor of greenhouse in Burning (2018)

Tags: plot-explanation, burning

Lee Chang-dong's *Burning* (2018) left me puzzled about the whole greenhouse burning business. Ben talks about metaphors and his strange hobby of burning greenhouses every two months or so. After multiple rewatches I think Ben killed Hae-mi is more plausible. If so, how come abandoned greenhouses serve as a metaphor for lower-class young South Korean women?